# error : can not reslove symbol 'R' whenever I'm trying to add appcompat-v7:22.0.0 dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, r.java-file

I'm working on a project built on the support-v4:22.0.0 dependency. Now I'm trying to add the Google Maps Activity.For adding Google Maps, appcompat-v7:22.0.0 dependency is adding to the Gradle. After adding this activity I'm getting the error in the Gradle Build Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'xxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx'. And also its showing Error: can not resolve 'R'.

I tried cleaning the project, syncing the Gradle, restarting the Andrid Studio. But nothing turned up. Please help me out

Comment: @RachitaNanda I found the answer :)

Comment: Ok then please accept your answer as well do that everyone gets to know you have found the solution :)

Comment: @RachitaNanda It shows that I have to wait for 2 days in order to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

Changing the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `21` in `src/build.gradle` did the job for me.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    ..........

    defaultConfig {
       ...........
       ...........
       targetSdkVersion 21
    }
```